# php search string for word if not found search another word

Tags: php, search, loops

I would like to search a string for a word and if this word is not found I'd like it to search for another word and keep going until it find one I have seen codes to search a string but not to keep searching.

Cheers
Ashley

P.s php code is what I need

Thank you very much for your help guys,

I will post my wip code in future thanks for the tip.

Comment: It was nice of someone to code this for you. Usually, it is better to at least try to code it yourself and provide us with the code that is failing to help you figure it out that way.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple:

```
$string = "This is the string I want to search in for a third word";

$words = array('first', 'second', 'third');
$found = '';
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (stripos($string, $words) !== false) {
        $found = $word;
        break;
    }
}
echo "This first match found was '$found'";
```

Note: Use [`strpos`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (or [`stripos`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) for case-insensitive search) since they only return an integer position.  Others such as [`strstr`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) return a portion of the string, which is un-necessary for this purpose.

**Edit:**

Or, without a loop you can do a single regex:

```
$words = array('first', 'second', 'third');
$regex = '/(' . implode('|', $words) . ')/i';
//$regex becomes '/(first|second|third)/i'
if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
    echo "The first match found was {$match[0]}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$haystack = 'PHP is popular and powerful';
$needles = array('Java','Perl','PHP');
$found = '';
foreach($needles as $needle) {
        if(strpos($haystack,$needle) !== false) {
                $found = $needle;
                break;
        }
}

if($found !== '') {
        echo "Needle $found found in $haystack\n";
} else {
        echo "No needles found\n";
}
```

The above code will consider sub-string matches as valid matches. For example if needle is `'HP'` it will be found as it is a sub-string of `PHP`.

To make full word matches you can make use of `preg_match` as:

```
foreach($needles as &$needle) {
        $needle = preg_quote($needle);
}

$pattern = '!\b('.implode('|',$needles).')\b!';

if(preg_match($pattern,$haystack,$m)) {
        echo "Needle $m[1] found\n";
} else {
        echo "No needles found\n";
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/dIP4y)

Answer (score 0):

If you place all the values in an array you'd like to search for, you could loop through that array until you find one that is in your string.

```
$string = "I love to eat tacos.";
$searchfor = array("brown", "lazy", "tacos");

foreach($searchfor as $v) {
  if(strpos($string, $v)) {
    //Found a word
    echo 'Found '.$v;
    break;
  }
}
```

This would output:

```
Found tacos
```

This is using `strpos` which is case-sensitive. If you don't care about case, you can use `stripos`.

[PHP: strpos](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Comment: `strpos` should be used here instead of `strstr`, see the note on the manual page you linked to :)

Comment: @mfonda Thanks, I think I really meant `strpos` but just kind of rushed through that. I've updated my answer to reflect the correct idea.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```
<?php


function first_found(array $patterns, $string) {
    foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
        if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
            return $matches;
        }
    }
}

$founded = first_found(
    array(
        '/foo/',
        '/bar/',
        '/baz/',
        '/qux/'
    ), 
    ' yep, it qux.'
);
```